# Start particular service from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and have docker-compose.yml which is containing many services and iI need to start one particular service. I have docker-compose.yml file with information:

```
version: '2'

services:
    
    postgres:
        image: ${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/datahub/postgres:${BUILD_NUMBER}
        restart: "no"
        volumes:
            - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd
            

        volumes_from:
            - libs
        depends_on:
            - libs

    setup:
        image: ${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/setup:${B_N}
        restart: "no"
        volumes:
            - ${HOME}:/usr/local/
```

I am able to call docker-compose.yml file using command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --no-build
```

But I need to start "setup service" in docker-compose file:

How can I do this?

Comment: You have two services called setup. This isn't valid.

Comment: apologies,i have edited the code ....please suggest what can i do

Answer (score 7):

It's very easy:

```bash
$ docker compose up <service-name>
```

In your case:

```bash
$ docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up setup -d
```

To stop the service, then you don't need to specify the service name:

```bash
$ docker compose down
```

will do.

Little side note: if you are in the directory where the `docker-compose.yml` file is located, then docker-compose will use it implicitly, there's no need to  add it as a parameter.
You need to provide it in the following situations:

- the file is not in your current directory
- the file name is different from the default one, eg. myconfig.yml

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question, you have multiple services in docker-compose but want to deploy only one.

docker-compose should be used for multi-container Docker applications. From official [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) :

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker
> applications.

IMHO, you should run your service image separately with docker run command.

**PS**: If you are asking about recreating only the container whose image is changed among the multiple services in your docker-compose file, then docker-compose handles that for you.